# Unable to login as regular user in Youtrack 6

Tags: youtrack

I'm getting following error while trying to login as a user. But i'm able to login as an admin.

`Authentication is temporarily unavailable. Please contact your server administrators.`

The youtrack license that i'm using is free license, installed on a D1 azure server.  YouTrack 6.0
Build 12124 [30-Oct-2014 22:27]

I googled the error message and found this `https://github.com/JetBrains/youtrack-l10n/blob/master/translations/en_US/all_en.properties`, in which it talks about the exception `# jetbrains.charisma.authentication.LoginIsAllowedForAdminsOnlyException
LoginIsAllowedForAdminsOnlyException`
But there is not such setting in the admin.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message is a signal of incorrect installation, that can be caused by several various reasons. As a solution please do the following:

- Upgrade to the latest bugfix build (we fix installation problems ASAP).
- If the message remains please submit a bug at youtrack.jetbrains.com with information about your installation type (JAR, ZIP or MSI) and build number. Please attach you instance logs to the issue.

Comment: Disabling Ring integration fixed the issue as of now.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not a fix, just a workaround. Disabling Ring Integration is just a temporary solution. I kindly ask you to consider my previous answer.

Comment: FYI, build 6.0.12223 has a href to 6.0.12124 here https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TSYSPUB/YouTrack+Release+Downloads+Archive

Comment: I am having this problem too.. I just upgraded from YouTrack 5.2 to YouTrack 6.0 build 12463. I had to disable Ring integration to be able to login.

Comment: @RosdiKasim Can I kindly ask you to create an issue at youtrack.jetbrains.com and attach you instance logs? We can investigate your issue with logs only.

Comment: Hi Leaom, I submitted some logs here: http://forum.jetbrains.com/thread/YouTrack-2094 I will submit in youtrack.jetbrains.com once I registered an account there. Thanks.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same, I'm using build youtrack-6.0.12463 with free license. I tried also to disable Ring integration and it doesn't work, that is I can login as root but it isn't impossible to login as user.

Comment: Please, I would like to disable ring integration but I'm not able to find this parameter ...